# mysqli prepared UPDATE statement not updating values in database

Tags: php, mysqli

After searching and referring to various pieces of documentation, I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

**What I'm Trying To Do**

I am trying to execute a prepared update statement on a database, using the following function:

```php
function _UPDATE_IP_BAD(&$mysqli, $id_of_ip, &$value){

    ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

    $timestamp = time();

    //  UPDATE `dbmxpca_ipinfo`.`list` SET `is_bad` = '0.0111000000000000000', `cached_bad` = '1553849540' WHERE (`id` = '2');
    $exec_data = array();

    $prepare = "UPDATE dbmxpca_ipinfo.list SET `is_bad`=?, `cached_bad`=? WHERE `id`=?";
    //$prepare = 'UPDATE dbmxpca_ipinfo.list SET `is_bad`=?, `cached_bad`=? WHERE `id`=?;';
    //$prepare = 'UPDATE dbmxpca_ipinfo.list SET is_bad=?, cached_bad=? WHERE id=?;';



    // $prepare = 'UPDATE `dbmxpca_ipinfo`.`list` SET is_bad=?, cached_bad=? WHERE id=?;';


    //$prepare = 'UPDATE `dbmxpca_ipinfo`.`list` SET ( `is_bad`, `cached_bad` ) VALUES (?, ?) WHERE (`id`=' . $id_of_ip . ');';

    //$prepare = 'UPDATE `dbmxpca_ipinfo`.`list` SET ( `is_bad`, `cached_bad` ) VALUES (?, ?) WHERE (`id`=' . $id_of_ip . ');';
    //$prepare = 'UPDATE `dbmxpca_ipinfo`.`list` SET `is_bad`=?, `cached_bad`=? WHERE (`id`=?);';

    //$prepare = 'UPDATE `dbmxpca_ipinfo`.`list` SET `is_bad`=?, `cached_bad`=? WHERE (`id`=?);';
    //$prepare = 'UPDATE `dbmxpca_ipinfo`.`list` SET `is_bad` = ?, `cached_bad` = ? WHERE (`id` = ?);';
    // $prepare = 'UPDATE `dbmxpca_ipinfo`.`list` SET `is_bad` = \'?\', `cached_bad` = \'?\' WHERE (`id` = \'?\');';
    //$bind_types = 'iii';
    $bind_types = 'dii';
    //$bind_types = 'idi';
    // $bind_types = 'di';
    //$bind_values = array($value, $timestamp);
    $bind_values = array($value, $timestamp, $id_of_ip);
    $exec_result = DB_EXEC2($mysqli, $prepare, $bind_types, $bind_values, $exec_data);

    if ($exec_result){

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I am calling it as such:

`UPDATE_IP_BAD($mysqli, 2, 0);`

($mysqli is already defined and initialized elsewhere).

**The Problem**

The issue is, DB_EXEC2() reports a successful query (1 rows affected, as it should be), but **neither of the two values are getting updated in the database.** No errors are reported, but the database values remain unchanged. Am I doing something wrong?

I have tried NUMEROUS different ways to write the prepared statement (the commented-out lines all did not work), and neither did the uncommented-one. I have even experimented with different bind types (integer vs double) all to no avail. I have been looking at this for hours and am completely stumped at what the issue could be. Even adding additional error reporting at the top of the function as I have seen suggested produced no errors.

DB_EXEC2() is a custom function to execute a prepared statement. It logs results of actions to a file. The function definition is as follows:

```php
function DB_EXEC2(&$mysqli, $prepare, $bind_types, &$bind_values, &$result_data = null){

    //  Get number of bind types.
    $nBindTypeCount = strlen($bind_types);

    //  Get number of bind values.
    $nBindValCount = count($bind_values);

    //  Make sure they match.
    if ($nBindTypeCount != $nBindValCount){

        $errmsg = 'DB_EXEC2 Error: [Number of bind types does not match number of bind parameters].';
        if (ENABLE_LOG_DB){
            \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'ERROR', $errmsg);
        }

        return false;
    }

    //  Prepare
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prepare);
    if ($stmt === false){

        //  ------------ Prepared statement error ------------

        $errmsg = 'SQL Prepared-Statement Error: [' . $mysqli->errno . ': ' . $mysqli->error . '].';
        if (ENABLE_LOG_DB){
            \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'ERROR', $errmsg);
        }

        $stmt->close();

        return false;
    }

    //  Make array of all params.
    $fparams = array();
    array_push($fparams, $bind_types);
    foreach($bind_values as $bvk){
        array_push($fparams, $bvk);
    }
    //  "hack" for a function I don't like: call_user_func_array().
    $ptrParams = array();
    $nParamCount = count($fparams);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nParamCount; $i++){
        $ptrParams[$i] = &$fparams[$i];
    }

    //  Dump values to log file for debugging.
    if (ENABLE_LOG_DB){

        \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', 'ptrParams Dump:');
        \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', '-----------------------');
        foreach ($ptrParams as $ptrParamsK){
            \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', '  ' . $ptrParamsK);
        }
        \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', '-----------------------');
    }

    //  Bind.
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $ptrParams);

    //  Attempt to execute.
    if ($stmt->execute() === true){

        //  ------------ Execution success ------------

        $errmsg = 'SQL execution successful:';
        if (ENABLE_LOG_DB){

            $errmsg = 'SQL execution successful.';
            \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', $errmsg);

            \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', 'Affected Rows = [' . $stmt->affected_rows . '].');
            \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', 'Error = [' . $stmt->error . '].');

        }

        //  TODO: If $result_data is null, just return true on success.     

        $result = $stmt->get_result();      
        if (!$result){

            //  ------------ GetResult Execution error ------------
            if (ENABLE_LOG_DB){
                $errmsg = 'GetResult Error: [' . $mysqli->error . ' - ' . mysqli_error($mysqli) . '].';
                \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'ERROR', $errmsg);
            }

            $stmt->close();
            return false;
        }
        else{

            //  ------------ GetResult Execution success ------------

            //  Create structure to store the results.
            if (!isset($result_data)){

                $result_data = array();
            }

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

                //  $result_data should hold all resulting rows. If we get 1 result as
                //  we normally should, all payload should be at $result_data[0].

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                    array_push($result_data, $row);
                }

                $stmt->close();
                return true;
            }
            else{

                //  No results
                $stmt->close();
                return true;
            }
        }


        $stmt->close();

        return true;

    }
    else{

        //  ------------ Execution error ------------

        $errsql = $stmt->error;
        $errsql2 = 'N/A';
        $errmsg = 'SQL Error: [' . $errsql . ': ' . $errsql2 . '].';
        if (ENABLE_LOG_DB){
            \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'ERROR', $errmsg);
        }

        $stmt->close();

        return false;
    }

}
```

Log output (for reference):

```
[06/25/2019 @ 01:18:34 AM EDT] [INFO] [@DB_EXEC2]: ptrParams Dump:
[06/25/2019 @ 01:18:34 AM EDT] [INFO] [@DB_EXEC2]: -----------------------
[06/25/2019 @ 01:18:34 AM EDT] [INFO] [@DB_EXEC2]:   dii
[06/25/2019 @ 01:18:34 AM EDT] [INFO] [@DB_EXEC2]:   0
[06/25/2019 @ 01:18:34 AM EDT] [INFO] [@DB_EXEC2]:   1561439914
[06/25/2019 @ 01:18:34 AM EDT] [INFO] [@DB_EXEC2]:   2
[06/25/2019 @ 01:18:34 AM EDT] [INFO] [@DB_EXEC2]: -----------------------
[06/25/2019 @ 01:18:34 AM EDT] [INFO] [@DB_EXEC2]: SQL execution successful.
[06/25/2019 @ 01:18:34 AM EDT] [INFO] [@DB_EXEC2]: Affected Rows = [1].
[06/25/2019 @ 01:18:34 AM EDT] [INFO] [@DB_EXEC2]: Error = [].
[06/25/2019 @ 01:18:34 AM EDT] [ERROR] [@DB_EXEC2]: GetResult Error: [ - ].
[06/25/2019 @ 01:18:34 AM EDT] [INFO] [@DB_CLOSE]: Closing database connection...
[06/25/2019 @ 01:18:34 AM EDT] [INFO] [@DB_CLOSE]: Done.
```

** UPDATE 1 **

Added this code thanks to @Your Common Sense:

```php
    $stmt = DB_EXEC3($mysqli, $sql, $aParams, $strBindTypes);

    if ($stmt === true){

        \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', "Success!");
        return true;
    }

    \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'ERROR', "stmt->execute() did not return true.");
    \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', "-- Error ID: $stmt->errno");
    \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', "-- Error: $stmt->error");
    if (isset($stmt->error_list)){

        \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', "-- Error List:");
        foreach ($stmt->error_list as $errk => $errv){
            \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', "---- $errk -> $errv");
        }
    }
    \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', "-- Affected rows: $stmt->affected_rows");
```

and the resulting log outputs this:

```
[06/25/2019 @ 04:14:25 AM EDT] [INFO] [@DB_CONNECT]: Attempting mysqli initialization... please wait.
[06/25/2019 @ 04:14:25 AM EDT] [ERROR] [@UPDATE_IP_BAD]: stmt->execute() did not return true.
[06/25/2019 @ 04:14:25 AM EDT] [INFO] [@UPDATE_IP_BAD]: -- Error ID: 0
[06/25/2019 @ 04:14:25 AM EDT] [INFO] [@UPDATE_IP_BAD]: -- Error: 
[06/25/2019 @ 04:14:25 AM EDT] [INFO] [@UPDATE_IP_BAD]: -- Error List:
[06/25/2019 @ 04:14:25 AM EDT] [INFO] [@UPDATE_IP_BAD]: -- Affected rows: 1
[06/25/2019 @ 04:14:25 AM EDT] [INFO] [@DB_CLOSE]: Closing database connection...
[06/25/2019 @ 04:14:25 AM EDT] [INFO] [@DB_CLOSE]: Done.
```

So basically, the system isn't reporting any errors (despite all error reporting is enabled, thanks to https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting

It seems to suggest everything went well (1 row affected) but in-fact the row data remains unchanged for some mysterious reason...

Comment: `is_bad` value is sting or integer or something else? Please tell

Comment: Also why you used calling by reference for `connection` and `$value` parameter of the function? And from where `$exec_data` came from in your `DB_EXEC2()`?

Comment: `is_bad` is an integer, either 0 or 1. `$connection` is passed by reference because I come from C/C++ and PHP doesn't seem to support "global" variables in the same manner, so I just pass the mysqli object directly. `$value` was passed by reference out of desperation ... was just trying my luck with it :)

Comment: for the goodness sake, change that monster DB_EXEC2() to this [simple helper function](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple)

Comment: As of your question, you are just one step from the answer. You did a magnificent job already, the rest is simple: add a *demonstrational example* to your question. Basically you need to add only 4 queries: create a temporary database, insert a test row in it, then run a SELECT query to show the result, then run your update and then another SELECT to display the outcome. The thing is called MCVE and here is an [instruction](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve) (albeit for PDO but the principle is the same)

Comment: I am not sure why you did that much code, check this simple code and try once:- https://3v4l.org/jBhLX (`mysqli_*` syntax/code is enough to do all tasks, so don't overburden yourself).

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks for the responses and tips! I am going to try that link you provided for the simple helper function and report back the results. Many thanks again! I will also update the question per your suggestion if I have further issues

Comment: `ipinfo.list.list` is not a valid table name. are you positively sure there are no errors and there are affected rows?

Comment: That's correct, wow my mistake. I tried to simplify the code before pasting it here, my apologies. I will copy/paste the original code

Comment: 1. `if ($stmt === true)` condition makes no sense, it will always return false.  You may want to write it as `if ($stmt)`, but with exceptions enabled such a condition makes no sense as well. 2. You didn't create an mcve as requested. To be frank: what you are claiming here is impossible. Either the data in the database is **changed** or there is an **error**. So your problem is either a typo of some sort or a measurement error. No other outcome is possible. The MCVE creation process is intended to help you find that error. Looks like your data is changed but for some reason you think it's not

Comment: @YourCommonSense The reason I say it's not is that I verified by looking at the database and refreshing it after running the code. I am not quite sure why its not working but it looks like the revision someone did does show it's working. Thank you for taking the time to be so detailed with your suggestions and advice -- your website has proven to be invaluable and I have bookmarked it so I can continue to refer to it for reference

Incidentally, I was on my mobile phone at the time and was unable to easily get some examples, hence why I didn't provide the MCVE that you requested

Comment: that said, i will definitely be sure to add such a thing in the future. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

As it turns out, the following option was set: `SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0` in the `DB_CONNECT()` function (that was not included in the original post). Removing it seems to have solved the issue.

So indeed, a third outcome *is* possible (contrary to what was said in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

I commented out the error logging parts (as I did not want to set contants and file paths etc), change the table name, and code seems to be working:

```
UPDATE_IP_BAD($mysqli, 1, 0);

function UPDATE_IP_BAD(&$mysqli, $id_of_ip, $value){

    ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

    $timestamp = time();
    $exec_data = array();

    $prepare = "UPDATE list SET `is_bad`=?, `cached_bad`=? WHERE `id`=?";
    $bind_types = 'dii';
    $bind_values = array($value, $timestamp, $id_of_ip);
    $exec_result = DB_EXEC2($mysqli, $prepare, $bind_types, $bind_values, $exec_data);

    if ($exec_result){

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}



    function DB_EXEC2(&$mysqli, $prepare, $bind_types, &$bind_values, &$result_data = null)
     {

       //  Get number of bind types.
       $nBindTypeCount = strlen($bind_types);

       //  Get number of bind values.
       $nBindValCount = count($bind_values);

       //  Make sure they match.
       if ($nBindTypeCount != $nBindValCount)
        {
            $errmsg = 'DB_EXEC2 Error: [Number of bind types does not match number of bind parameters].';
          /*  if (ENABLE_LOG_DB)
              {
                 \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'ERROR', $errmsg);
              }
*/
             return false;
         }

          //  Prepare
         $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prepare);
         if($stmt === false)
          {
             //  ------------ Prepared statement error ------------
             $errmsg = 'SQL Prepared-Statement Error: [' . $mysqli->errno . ': ' . $mysqli->error . '].';
           /*  if (ENABLE_LOG_DB)
              { 
                  \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'ERROR', $errmsg);
              } */
          $stmt->close();
          return false;
         }

         //  Make array of all params.
         $fparams = array();
         array_push($fparams, $bind_types);
         foreach($bind_values as $bvk)
          {
            array_push($fparams, $bvk);
          }

         // "hack" for a function I don't like: call_user_func_array().
         $ptrParams = array();
         $nParamCount = count($fparams);
          for ($i = 0; $i < $nParamCount; $i++)
            {
               $ptrParams[$i] = &$fparams[$i];
            }

          //  Dump values to log file for debugging.
       /*  if(ENABLE_LOG_DB)
          {
             \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', 'ptrParams Dump:');
              \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', '-----------------------');
             foreach ($ptrParams as $ptrParamsK)
               {
                    \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', '  ' . $ptrParamsK);
               }
              \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', '-----------------------');
           } */

         //  Bind.
         call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $ptrParams);

         //  Attempt to execute.
         if ($stmt->execute() === true)
           {

              //  ------------ Execution success ------------
              $errmsg = 'SQL execution successful:';
            /*  if(ENABLE_LOG_DB)
               {
                   $errmsg = 'SQL execution successful.';
                   \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', $errmsg);
                   \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', 'Affected Rows = [' . $stmt->affected_rows . '].');
                   \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'INFO', 'Error = [' . $stmt->error . '].');
               }
*/
        //  TODO: If $result_data is null, just return true on success.     

        $result = $stmt->get_result();      
        if (!$result){

            //  ------------ GetResult Execution error ------------
        /*    if (ENABLE_LOG_DB){
                $errmsg = 'GetResult Error: [' . $mysqli->error . ' - ' . mysqli_error($mysqli) . '].';
                \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'ERROR', $errmsg);
            }
 */
            $stmt->close();
            return false;
        }
        else{

            //  ------------ GetResult Execution success ------------

            //  Create structure to store the results.
            if (!isset($result_data)){

                $result_data = array();
            }

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

                //  $result_data should hold all resulting rows. If we get 1 result as
                //  we normally should, all payload should be at $result_data[0].

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                    array_push($result_data, $row);
                }

                $stmt->close();
                return true;
            }
            else{

                //  No results
                $stmt->close();
                return true;
            }
        }


        $stmt->close();

        return true;

    }
    else{

        //  ------------ Execution error ------------

        $errsql = $stmt->error;
        $errsql2 = 'N/A';
        $errmsg = 'SQL Error: [' . $errsql . ': ' . $errsql2 . '].';
    /*    if (ENABLE_LOG_DB){
            \SYSTEM\DBMSLOG2(DB_LOGNAME, 'ERROR', $errmsg);
        }
*/
        $stmt->close();

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I updated it and still no avail. The timestamp by the way, is generated from PHP's `time()` function (which returns UNIX timestamp) so if I'm not mistaken I think it should probably be integer. I tried your suggestion anyway and still no luck :(

Comment: Let me take a proper look at this code.  I had my coffee now :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I copied this to a new file and after initializing the $mysqli it looks like it worked flawlessly and updated the value as expected. Now to figure out what I had missing tomorrow morning lol. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, your functions are very hard to read. Let me suggest you a [very simple mysqli helper function](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple) I wrote instead. With it your code will become

```
function UPDATE_IP($mysqli, $id_of_ip, $value){
    $prepare = "UPDATE list SET `is_bad`=?, `cached_bad`=? WHERE `id`=?";
    $bind_values = array($value, time(), $id_of_ip);
    return mysqli($mysqli, $prepare, $bind_values)->affected_rows();
}
```

Now you can call it this way

```
$num_rows = UPDATE_IP_BAD($mysqli, 2, 0);
echo $num_rows;
```

and it should display the number of rows affected.

I just noticed that `ipinfo.list.list` is not a valid table name, so there **must** be an error. You have to configure mysqli properly in order to see mysql errors. Please kindly refer to this [canonical mysqli connection code](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect) I wrote that among other things configires the error reporting. Having it set, you will see the error immediately.

Comment: My sincere apologies; I did make a mistake when copy/pasting a modified version originally when pasting the question. I have updated the original post with the actual code, so sorry. Thanks again for the help